# HAProxy balancer using the url_param value?

Tags: hash, load-balancing, haproxy

I have 3 different restful servers: w1, w2, w3

My clients that refer to my load balancer are providing the url parameter called "ip" (ipv4). The url parameter ip is different between a requests:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/link?ip=x.x.x.x
```

I would like to balance with HAProxy to w1, w2, w3 according to the ip parameter using HASH algo.

HAProxy configuration below:

```
global
    #daemon
    maxconn 3000

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend workers

backend workers
    balance url_param ip
    hash-type consistent
    server w1 localhost:8080 weight 1 maxconn 1000 check
    server w2 localhost:8081 weight 1 maxconn 1000 check
    server w3 localhost:8082 weight 1 maxconn 1000 check

listen admin
    bind *:8088
    stats hide-version
    stats realm HAProxy\ statistics
    stats enable
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi. I tried out the configuration you specified and it seemed to match the description of what you asked for already. Can you provide an example of what doesn't work with your current configuration? My other question is is the command at the top of the post the test command? If so shouldn't you be trying to connect to localhost on port 80 to see if it load balances, not port 8080, or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

With HAProxy 1.6.4 (and lower versions) choose the source balance algorithm. I think this algorithm should do your job or was there a reason for choosing `balance url_param` ?

```
balance source
hash-type consistent
```

The hash-type is optional but could be useful. [Here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#hash-type) some further information.